# Integrate CodeIgniter with phpBB3 User System

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, phpbb3

Is there a way to integrate CodeIgniter with phpBB3? I would like to use the user system as a base for my future CodeIgniter Application.

Is it a good idea to use phpBB as a base user system?

Comment: Take care! I fell into this pit once! PhpBB automatically creates user accounts for robots like Googlebot. You can tell, I was surprised when I found the heart of my application, where only hand-selected people should have access to, at the Google cache, visible for everyone. **Don't use an external user authentication system, if you don't really understand how it works!**

Comment: ...I did, by the way, the same thing you're up to: Using PhpBB's authentication for my own site, although not CI based.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.

Hmm maybe there's a way to disable the googlebot account D:! How did it work besides that small fluke? did it work as expected?

Anything else I should be aware about besides that tragic incident?

Comment: I deleted them, then they're gone and do no harm anymore. But in the first place, you have to know they exist. Actually they are described in the PhpBB docs, but you have to make the mental connection between their existence and the bots being able to read your protected content.

Comment: Oh, for the rest: It works just fine now. I still use it, and there were no complaints from the users (except for when I forgot to put the "get a new password" link on my custom login page...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Thorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150514/good-idea-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-phpbb3-user-system/1665572#1665572) pointed out, you can use [phpBB3 Library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/phpBB3_library/) available on CodeIgniter's website.

Along with that, you could create a phpBB user group and assign only "real" users to that group and have your CI authentication check for that group. This way, you won't get Googlebot peeking where it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

kuroir. You can look into http://codeigniter.com/wiki/phpBB3_library/ which is in the CodeIgniter wiki.